# How to get UITextField.tag+1?

Tags: iphone, tags, uitextfield

I am trying to make changes in a textfield which is very next textfield. e.g. if i call a TextFieldShouldReturn method (At that time tag which comes in this method is 0 and i want to perform action on a textfield who's tag is 1)and now i try that to make my very next textField to becomeFirst Responder. Both textFields have same IBOutlet but different tags.

I am a newbie so kindly don't mind my silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIViews method [`viewWithTag:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW26) to get the next UITextField.

maybe something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1];
    [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to obtain the tag number in textFieldShouldReturn method ?

Here is the way :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    int tag = textField.tag; // then do whatever you want with this information
}
```